# Using OneHot Encoder to split one column into four

Tags: python, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

In Python, suppose I have a column of a data frame called size, which looks like this:

```
E 
G 
F  
D 
F
E...
```

The letters D through G represent different sizes, say, from Small to X-Large. What I could do is represent them numerically, as so:

```
2
4
3
1
3
2...
```

However, since this is not continuous data, this may cause future problems with other analyses I'll do. Therefore, another idea I had was to split this into 4 columns, where an instance of the size is 1, otherwise, 0. It should look like this:

```
D E F G

0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0
```

I heard of something called OneHotEncoder in Python that is useful for these kind of scenarios. How would I use this effectively to solve this problem, or, what other ways can I go about this?

Comment: You are looking for pandas function [get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html). 

Example: `pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']))`.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you @DavidGasquez!